# xmlapi.php Does not work while trying to create account in cPanel

Tags: php, whm

I am trying to create a new account (temp domain) in my WHM. I am using the xmlapi.php api file which I have taken from [CpanelInc/xmlapi-php](https://github.com/CpanelInc/xmlapi-php)

From that Api I am using the createacct function. I have written this code so far

```
require_once("xmlapi.php");
$xmlapi = new xmlapi($ip);
$xmlapi->password_auth($user,$pass);
$xmlapi->set_debug(1);
$acct = array(username => "testdomain", password => "mSWyae2i", domain => "example.info");
$xml = $xmlapi->createacct($acct);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($xml);
```

I think I have written the code correct but the API is not working or it does not respond anything. When I run the page, the page keeps on loading and loading and loading...

Can I get some help please.? Also let me know what to pass in $ip ??

Answer (score 0):

If you run the PHP script on the same server where you want to create the new cPanel account then you should set the $ip to '127.0.0.1' otherwise set it to the public IP address of the server. Also you should set the port number to 2087. Here is an example which should work:

```
require_once('xmlapi.php');
$xmlapi = new xmlapi('127.0.0.1');
$xmlapi->set_port(2087);
$xmlapi->password_auth('whm_root_username_here', 'whm_root_password_here');
$xmlapi->set_debug(1);
$acct = array('username' => 'desired_cpanel_username_here', 'password' => 'desired_cpanel_password_here', 'domain' => 'example.info');
$xml = $xmlapi->createacct($acct);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($xml);
```